# Sorting an array and saving its output in variable

Tags: arrays, bash, sorting

I have an array

```
array = (Testcase_5_Input_Packets Testcase_3_Input_Packets
 Testcase_1_Input_Packets Testcase_4_Input_Packets Testcase_2_Input_Packets)
```

i want to sort its elements and save its sorted contents in an array to be like:

```
array = Testcase_1_Input_Packets
        Testcase_2_Input_Packets
        Testcase_3_Input_Packets
        Testcase_4_Input_Packets
        Testcase_5_Input_Packets
```

How do i do that in bash ?

Comment: Different to zsh,  bash does not have a facitlity for sorting arrays. If you want to stick with bash, I think you have to write the array to a file and invoke `sort`, and then recreate the array from the output of `sort`. However this will fail if the elements in your array contain newlines; they don't in your concrete example, but you need to ensure that this is not the case for the real data which you are processing.

Answer (score 2):

If array elements don't contain newline characters, then this one-liner should do the trick:

```
readarray -t sorted_array < <(printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}" | sort)
```

Comment: I tried it. It doesn't sort the array elements. I think because we need to use an option in sort function to sort the numbers in the string as our string contains letters and numbers.

Comment: @FarahBayomi It sorts. The sorted array is assigned to `sorted_array`. Run `printf '%s\n' "${sorted_array[@]}"` after the command and you'll see.

Comment: @FarahBayomi Or replace `sorted_array` with `array` in the command.

Answer (score -1):

IF your data contains no newlines, then this is straightforward:

```
rawdata=("Data 1" "Data 3" "Data 2" "Data 4")
tmpfile=/dev/shm/tmp.$$
touch "$tmpfile"
chmod 600 "$tmpfile"
for e in "${rawdata[@]}" 
do
    echo "$e" >> "$tmpfile"
done
sortdata=$(cat "$tmpfile" | sort)
echo "$sortdata" > "$tmpfile"
sortedarray=()
while read line
do
    sortedarray+=("$line")
done < "$tmpfile"
rm -f "$tmpfile"
```

BUT: This will break if an element includes a newline, as that's what sort uses as a delimeter.  This is solvable, but you'd need to ID a string that isn't used in your data, trade in-element newlines for that as you write them to the file, and trade them back as you read them out.  Once you've ID'd the string, that would look something like:

```
rawdata=("Data 1" "Data 3" "Data 2" "Data 4")
tmpfile=/dev/shm/tmp.$$
touch "$tmpfile"
chmod 600 "$tmpfile"
for element in "${rawdata[@]}" 
do
    alteration=$(echo "$element" | sed 's/\n/NEWLINEMARKER/g')
    alteration=$(echo "$alteration" | sed 's/NEWLINEMARKER$//g')
    echo "$alteration" >> "$tmpfile"
done
sortdata=$(cat "$tmpfile" | sort)
echo "$sortdata" > "$tmpfile"
sortedarray=()
while read line
do
    element=$(echo "$line" | sed 's/NEWLINEMARKER/\n/g')
    sortedarray+=("$element")
done < "$tmpfile"
rm -f "$tmpfile"
```

Good Coding!

Comment: I tried the first solution. It produces a syntax error in the first do. 

bash: trial2.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''
'ash: trial2.sh: line 6: `do